# Version control for subtitle creation

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

We make subtitles for a TV series and I plan to use a VCS for it.
The structure of project directory is like this:

```
series/
    episode1/nameofepisode1.str
    episode2/nameofepisode2.str
    episode3/nameofepisode3.str
    ...
```

Question: When I finish subtitle of an `episode`, I want to assign release tag for this `episode` (episode1_v1). I wanted to use `git` for this, but in git tag is assigned only to the whole repository.

What to do, so that I can view every `episode` progress separately? Maybe there are some more suitable VCS for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Changing my mind...)

> What to do, so that I can view every episode progress separately?

If you see the production of subtitles for the entire series as a single project, using a single Git repository initialised in the `series` directory makes sense. That way, you'll be able to track the progress on all episodes under a single repo, but that won't prevent you from viewing the progress on only one particular file, using, for instance

```
git log -- episode1/nameofepisode1.str
```

or

```
git diff episode1_v1..HEAD -- episode1/nameofepisode1.str
```

> I want to assign release tag for this episode (episode1_v1). I wanted to use git for this, but in git tag is assigned only to the whole repository.

If you see each episode as a distinct *feature* in your project, it make sense to use a tag to mark an episode's release. That won't prevent you from doing minor fixes such as typos further after the release.

Comment: Thank you. I came to conclusion not to use tags. I'll use `git log ...` for single file. I'm going to mark important milestones in commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you tag, you tag not file(s) (or any other **physical** object) in repository, but *existing changeset* (logical object) (i.e state of repository at some moment), which, by design, defined for the whole content
2. I can't see any sense in tagging of intermediate work, for history you can use ordinary log of `episode1/nameofepisode1.str` file
3. In SVN, where tagging is just conventional copy to /tags/, you can `svn copy` single file

Answer (score 0):

Some older version control systems allow you to assign tags to individual versions of individual files, but this is really not a proper use of tags anyway.

I would suggest you make the status of individual files visible e.g. by using a naming convention.  In other words, when a file is finished, you'd rename it, or move it to a different directory.

Comment: I can't rename `.str` file, but moving `episode` subdirectory to different place is good advise. I think I'll use it if nothing better appears.

Comment: Moving files simply to indicate that they've reached a certain state would kind of defeat Git's purpose, though.